# Bot Framework + Telegram - до сервера не доходят координаты, видео и контакты

Tags: c#, бот, telegram, bot-framework

Беру стандартный шаблон приложения Bot Framework. Упрощаю в нём метод Post, чтобы для любого входящего сообщения поступало ответное Tadaaa:

```
public async Task<Message> Post([FromBody]Message message)
{
    return message.CreateReplyMessage("Tadaa");
}
```

Т. е. меняю только это.

Ок. Иду на портал Bot Framework, регистрирую бота. Возвращаюсь к коду, добавляю туда AppID и Primary app secret. Публикую бота в Azure с бесплатным планом F1. Регистрирую бота в Телеграме и сконнекчиваю его с серверной частью на портале.

Работает почему-то наполовину: до сервера доходят текстовые сообщения, фотографии или какой-нибудь файл (вордовский, например). Т. е. я получаю в ответ "Tadaaa". Но когда отправляю контакты, видео или координаты (а мне как раз нужны именно координаты) - ответа нет никакого.

Почему? Из того, что ответа нету, сделал вывод, что до сервера сообщение не доходит. Спросил на англоязычном stackoverflow, поскольку там вся движуха пока что, - пока что ответили, что это с сервером что-то. Но я проделал всё вышеперечисленное ещё раз - эффект тот же.

Может, это ограничения бесплатного плана или эти вложения должны обрабатываться другим методом? Я программист так себе, кодю в качестве хобби :)

Хотелось бы услышать мнение тех, кто уже создавал телеграм-ботов в паре с Bot Framework.